# Embed Stack Overflow (mechanism or itself) into my website

Tags: support, integration

I was wondering if I can have Stack Overflow capabilities inside my website. For example WordPress can be installed on a host as if it was an application. Is there a way of installing simple (Stack Overflow) on my host?  Also, what's the name of this technique? Is that what the API is? Pr that's different thing?

P.S.: "I have a domain on (bluehost, Cpanel, simple scripts) , with WordPress installed"

If the above isn't available is it possible for me to embed my profile (questions, rating, flair etc) or embed someone important questions into my blog? Should I do that using websites embedding plugins or there is already something good on WordPress?

Comment: Seems like it *might* be a question for either http://meta.stackoverflow.com or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: when there gonna be the possibility of forwarding wrong placed questions to the right places with a click :D just wondering

Comment: oh it just did that :D wow

Answer (score 11):

You can use one of the many clones to host your own question and answer site on your webhost, but it won't come with the community or questions already on stackoverflow.

You can embed your stackoverflow profile onto your website using your user flair.  This image can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

If you want to have certain questions or answers (such as your own questions and answers) show up on your website, you can accomplish this using the Stackoverflow API. It's read only at the moment, so anyone who might want to participate in questions you're involved in will have to go to stackoverflow and participate there, but it will get your stackoverflow Q&A on your own site.  Details about the stack overflow API are here: https://stackapps.com/

Comment: And of course you can pull your user activity stream into [any system that supports Atom feeds.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/)

Comment: For embedding questions try [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere)

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow itself doesn't offer this functionality, it's closed source software and available in hosted form only under special conditions.

Check out the [list of Stack Overflow clones.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) You may be able to embed one of them in a PHP environment (although I expect it's not going to be trivial).

Comment: embed one of them ..hah

Comment: Companies would PAY StackOverflow for the ability to embed a community on their web site (filtered by their product of course). For example Apple would like to embed all iPhone-related topics on their web site.

Comment: I'm helping a non-profit group setup their squarespace account. I needed to ask a question and was surprised to see their FAQ/QA area is very much like Stack Overflow (and their varieties). How were they able to accomplish this? Did Squarespace pay $$$ to have this ability? https://answers.squarespace.com/index.html

Comment: @HPWD definitely looks like a clone. Not the original product. Not sure which one of the existing clones, though.

Comment: Pëkka thanks for confirming it isn't the original code. I've seen clones but wow is theirs close.